# fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle

Tags: assembly, gnu, att

I am making a program in at&t assembly using the GNU compiler that needs to use fread. however when the program reaches that part of the program i get an error message:  "fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle" I have been unable to find out what it means or how it could be fixed and would like some help with that. here is the relevant code:

```
    .bss
    file: (.asciz "") #attempted both with and without
    reader: .asciz ""
    pointer:
    .text
    readmode: .asciz "r"
    .global main
    main
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    movq 8(%rsi), %rdi    #moving a the filename to rdi
    movq $readmode, %rsi  #setting the mode to read only
    call fopen
    movq %rax, (file)
    call readchar

readchar:    #this should read in precisely one character at a time
    leaq reader, %rdi
    movq $1, %rsi
    movq $1, %rdx
    movq $file, %rcx
    call fread
```

on `call fread` the error happens

Comment: You should learn assembly syntax. What do you think `.asciz ""` does? That's not the right way to reserve storage for a variable.

Comment: It's also possible to get it from C, it just happened to me using GCC.